# How to execute javascript iframe in custom module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have created a custom module for Drupal 7. In this module, I would like it execute a javascript file that embeds an iframe when the module is viewed. I have tried the following code with no success:

```
function chat_with_librarian_block_view($delta = '') {

  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'chat_with_librarian':
      $block['subject'] = t('Ask a Librarian');
      $block['content'] = chat_with_librarian_get_html();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function chat_with_librarian_get_html() {

  $html = '<div id="qpchatwidget" >' .
    '</div>' .
    '<script ...call site in question with appropriate parameters...>' .
    '<noscript>Please enable javascript to chat with librarians online</noscript></script>';
  $form = array(
    'chat_frame' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $html,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="parent">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    )
  );
  return $form;
}
```

What do I need to do to get the embedded javascript to work properly. As a side note I can make this work by creating a block through the administration screen, so I know this can be done. I just need to know what I am missing in my code to accomplish the same thing. When I do execute this code, the title is rendered but the body isn't. Examining the body of the block, I can see it contains the javascipt as returned by the function and an additional message:

```
Reload the page to get source for: url
```

It seems like the executing code cannot get correct div dimensions to return a proper iframe (but that is just a guess on my part - have put inline css to define a size). Has anyone come across something like this or how to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The reason why this wasn't working is because the div statement:

```
<div id="qpchatwidget" ></div>
```

is on one line. If you break it up into two lines:

```
<div id="qpchatwidget" >
</div>
```

Then everything works as it should. Amazing how something so simple can mess you up.

Comment: Can you explain why? I thought html is not sensitive to white space.

Comment: I am not sure why this is but I have experienced this issue before in other circumstances. The morale of the story is always to keep everything on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

The `$form` var in `chat_with_librarian_get_html()`is rather useless, just return the `$html` var instead and it should work.

```
function chat_with_librarian_get_html() {
  $html = '<div id="parent"><div id="qpchatwidget" ></div>' .
    '<script ...call site in question with appropriate parameters...>' .
    '<noscript>Please enable javascript to chat with librarians online</noscript></script></div>';
  return $html;
}
```

Comment: I tried this originally and it didn't work. I thought that perhaps I needed to return a form but that ended up with the same result.